# Import Assets in GEE as Geometries

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, feature-collection

I have a series of shapefiles in GEE with a single polygon for every .shp but they are imported as `FeatureCollection`. Is it possible to import them as `Geometry` or, alternatively, to convert them after the import (maybe using the JSON metadata)?

Just to clarify, every `FeatureCollection` is described as:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "columns": {
    "Id": "Long",
    "fid": "Long",
    "num": "Long",
    "site": "Long",
    "system:index": "String"
  },
  "version": 1658334898370181,
  "id": "users/abcd/geom1",
  "properties": {
    "label": "geom_1",
    "system:asset_size": 5472
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              53.366,
              26.749
            ],
            [
              53.367,
              26.749
            ],
            [
              53.367,
              26.749
            ],
            [
              53.366,
              26.749
            ],
            [
              53.366,
              26.749
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "00000000000000000000",
      "properties": {
        "Id": 387,
        "fid": 389,
        "a": 1,
        "b": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I'd like to have something like:

```
var geom_1 = 
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[53.366, 26.749],
            [53.367, 26.749],
            [53.367, 26.749],
            [53.366, 26.749],
            [53.366, 26.749]]], null, false),
        {
          "label": "geom_1",
          "system:index": "0"
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earth Engine's asset *storage* can only store feature collections (sometimes called “tables” in this context). So, you must convert when you *use* the asset in your script.

The simplest thing to do, when you want a `Geometry` and you know the file contained one polygon, is to call [`collection.geometry()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-geometry). This is not wise for large and complex geometry (that is expensive to process as a single unit), but fine for simple geometry.

If you want a `Feature` instead, then call [`collection.first()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-first) to get the single feature out of it. (Note that the upload process will sometimes split geometries into multiple features, so `first()` would only get some of it, but only if they are very complex, so that shouldn't be a problem here.)

Comment: It works indeed; but is there a way to keep the FeatureCollection property as well?

Comment: I mean using ```.geometry()```.

Comment: @HyPhens Geometries never have properties, so that means you want the `Feature`, not the `Geometry`, and you will need to use `collection.first()` to obtain that.